# Fancybox how to open dynamically with a variable

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2, fancybox-3

so right now I'm trying to load a fancybox modal with a javascript string I got back from an Ajax call.  What ends up happening is the modal opens up with this code inside rather than converting them to the appropriate images/thumbnails.

```
[{ src : 'e2121a1caf564e92be14cfb38d094901/9234b96c09_640.jpg', opts : { thumb: 'e2121a1caf564e92be14cfb38d094901/9234b96c09_640.jpg' } }]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what version are you using, here is an example for v3:

```
$.fancybox.open([
  {
    src   : 'https://source.unsplash.com/i-FqQIkJMqg/1536x2304',
    thumb : 'https://source.unsplash.com/i-FqQIkJMqg/200x200'
  }, 
  {
    src   : 'https://source.unsplash.com/z55CR_d0ayg/1279x853',
    thumb : 'https://source.unsplash.com/z55CR_d0ayg/200x200'
  }
]);
```

Comment: Hey Janis, that does work when I have that hard coded, but if I try to pass  the src as a javascript string, it does not load the images.

Comment: I guess your "javascript string" is not correct then. Try to debug your code to see if you are really passing a valid source.